# C# : Error CS9010 "Primary constructor body is not allowed"

Tags: c#

```
class staff:schoolMember
  {
    private int _Salary=60000;
    public int getSalary();
    {
      return _Salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int e)
    {
      _Salary=e;
    }
  }
```

This is part of my C# code, and an error occurs at ***line 2*** and I'm not sure what this error means, and I don't see the error in my code. Please help! Thankyou!

Comment: Remove the `;` after getSalary().

Comment: Besides what @sloth pointed out, you should really work on your naming conventions. Maybe take a look at [this](https://www.dofactory.com/reference/csharp-coding-standards). [Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/properties) might be of interest to you as well.

Comment: Also, you might as well use properties, as it is C#. So instead of a "normal" method, you create a property with a `get` and a `set` method. You can read more on tutorialspoint: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_properties.htm

Answer (score 2):

remove `;` after `getSalary()`

and make `_Salary` type consistent with `SetSalary()` parameter type

```
class staff : schoolMember
{
    private int _Salary = 60000;
    public int GetSalary()
    {
        return _Salary;
    }
    public void SetSalary(int e)
    {
        _Salary = e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou so much, this stopped the error.

Comment: You are welcome