# How to fix? error CS9010: Primary constructor body is not allowed c#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Help fix the code. I tried to write a code that helps to sum 15 given fractions, but when i run the code it throws an error:

> "error CS9010: Primary constructor body is not allowed"

An error was detected in a method that should sum fractions.

```
using System;

using System.Collections.Generic;

using System.Linq;

using System.Text;

using System.Threading.Tasks;


    class Program
    {    

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyStruct Q = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            Q.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + Q.c);
            Q.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + Q.z);
            
            MyStruct W = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            W.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + W.c);
            W.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + W.z);
            
            MyStruct E = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            E.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + E.c);
            E.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + E.z);
            
            MyStruct R = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            R.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + R.c);
            R.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + R.z);
            
            MyStruct T = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            T.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + T.c);
            T.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + T.z);
            
            MyStruct Y = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            Y.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + Y.c);
            Y.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + Y.z);
            
            MyStruct U = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            U.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + U.c);
            U.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + U.z);
            
            MyStruct I = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            I.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + I.c);
            I.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + I.z);
            
            MyStruct O = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            O.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + O.c);
            O.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + O.z);
            
            MyStruct P = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            P.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + P.c);
            P.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + P.z);
            
            MyStruct A = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            A.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + A.c);
            A.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + A.z);
            
            MyStruct S = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            S.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + S.c);
            S.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + S.z);
            
            MyStruct D = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            D.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + D.c);
            D.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + D.z);
            
            MyStruct F = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            F.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + F.c);
            F.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + F.z);
            
            MyStruct G = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            G.c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Числитель дроби = " + G.c);
            G.z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Знаменатель дроби = " + G.z);
 
            MyStruct c;
            c = Program.SummStruct(Q,W,E,R,T,Y,U,I,O,P,A,S,D,F,G);
 
            Console.WriteLine("Cложение: " + Q.ToString() + "+" + W.ToString() + "+" + E.ToString() + "+" + R.ToString() + "+" + T.ToString() + "+" + Y.ToString() + "+" + U.ToString() + "+" + I.ToString() + "+" + O.ToString() + "+" + P.ToString() + "+" + A.ToString() + "+" + S.ToString() + "+" + D.ToString() + "+" + F.ToString() + "+" + G.ToString() + "=" + c.ToString());
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
 
        public static MyStruct SummStruct(params MyStruct[] p) => p.Aggregate((f,s) => SummStruct(f,s)); //error here
        {
            MyStruct t = new MyStruct(0, 0);
            t.c = (a.c * b.z + a.z * b.c);
            t.z = a.z * b.z;
            return t;
 
        }
        public struct MyStruct
        {
            public double c;
            public double z;
 
            public MyStruct(int c, int z)
            {
                this.c = c;
                this.z = z;
            }
            public override string ToString()
            {
                return "(" + c.ToString() + "/" + z.ToString() + ")";
            }
 
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# : Error CS9010 "Primary constructor body is not allowed"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53579511/c-sharp-error-cs9010-primary-constructor-body-is-not-allowed)

Comment: remove the ; here         public static MyStruct SummStruct(params MyStruct[] p) => p.Aggregate((f,s) => SummStruct(f,s))

Comment: *when i run the code it throws an error* << Then you have shared with us a compile time error.

Comment: SummStruct has two bodies once via the lambda operator and once as classic body between {}. Make up your mind up what you really want here.

Comment: It's also worth noting that over half of the code you've presented is your Main method, which isn't where the problem is. Please read about [mcve] and read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Answer (score 2):

It think you're trying to achieve this:

```
public static MyStruct SummStruct(
    params MyStruct[] p) 
    => p.Aggregate(
        seed: new MyStruct(0,0),
        func: (a,b) => 
    {
        MyStruct t = new MyStruct(0, 0);
        t.c = (a.c * b.z + a.z * b.c);
        t.z = a.z * b.z;
        return t;
    });
```

It may be clearer to split this into two methods:

```
public static MyStruct SummStruct(
    params MyStruct[] p) 
    => p.Aggregate(
        seed: new MyStruct(0,0),
        func: (acc,next) => SumTwo(acc,next)); 

public static MyStruct SumTwo(MyStruct a, MyStruct b)
{
    MyStruct t = new MyStruct(0, 0);
    t.c = (a.c * b.z + a.z * b.c);
    t.z = a.z * b.z;
    return t;

}
```

Other notes:

1. `c`, `z` are fields and the c# way is for them to be [properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/properties).
2. You could move the SumTwo inside `MyStruct`.
3. You may want to use a [record](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/tutorials/records) type.

Comment: Gives an error when compiling: 
Unhandled Exception:
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: s
  at System.Int32.Parse (System.String s) [0x00003] in <62b430b945fa49a19a75382ef03e7bed>:0 
  at Struct.Program.Main (System.String[] args) [0x005a7] in <57272967cd0a401faf059d96134d78ec>:0 
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Answer (score 1):

remove `;` in this line:

```
public static MyStruct SummStruct(params MyStruct[] p) => p.Aggregate((f,s) => SummStruct(f,s));
```

Comment: After removing the `;` the code still won't compile! Due to the fact that you have `=>` an anonymous lambda and `{}` a code block.

Comment: @PeterCsalat  `t.c = (a.c * b.z + a.z * b.c);`   What are `a and c` in this part of the code? This code may have other errors. But it is better to read the question first. Thank you

Comment: Your proposed solution solves only the `CS9010` error. After your suggested change the code still won't compile. Solving only the `CS9010` issue IMHO is just half of the story. If you focus only on that part of the issue then I think it might make sense to mention this inside the post itself.

Comment: @PeterCsala anyway, i think that the vote down is for the wrong answer!

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you wrote 2 implementations of `SummStruct` method.

So, there are 2 ways to solve this problem.

**Write your method like this:**

```
public static MyStruct SummStruct(params MyStruct[] p) => p.Aggregate((f,s) => SummStruct(f,s));
```

**Or like this:**

```
public static MyStruct SummStruct(params MyStruct[] p)
{
    MyStruct t = new MyStruct(0, 0);
    t.c = (a.c * b.z + a.z * b.c);
    t.z = a.z * b.z;
    return t;
}
```

Comment: Both given source codes here are broken. The first ends up in a stackoverflow the second won't compile.

Comment: I understand, but I guess the main question was about error CS9010